# Format number with localizednumber('currency') give me ¤ instead $

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a symfony app, and I change locale in app/config/config.yml based on user preference.

I'm using this twig filter(from intl extension) on my template

```
<td> {{ entity.total | localizednumber('currency')}} </td>
```

For example, using 'es' locale I want this output

```
Id  Total   
28  250,00 $
```

For 'en' locale I want this output:

```
Id  Total   
28  $ 250.00
```

**However I get this output:**

```
Id  Total   
28  250,00 ¤
```

So what is that ¤ simbol? A error or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: ¤ is a "wildcard" [currency sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_sign_(typography)) to use when the actual currency is unknown. It seems like the currency/locale is not specified at the moment whrn it's rendered.

Comment: it seems that 'es' and 'en' are ambiguous locales, fixed with 'es_AR' and 'en_US'

Answer (score 0):

You probably declare the charset `iso-8859-1` instead  of `iso-8859-15`

- in `iso-8859-1`, `0xA4` represent ¤
- in `iso-8859-15`, `0xA4` represent €